# How to delete one gameObject with a tag in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, destroy

I have a map made of 6 blocks with a tag LevelBlock. After the car leaves the block it was currently on I want to delete that block. Now my code deletes random LevelBlock but not the one the car was previously on. How do I delete the LevelBlock that is no longer in use?

[image: Screenshot of the map here]

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Diagnostics;

public class TriggerExit : MonoBehaviour {

public float delay = 5f;

public delegate void ExitAction();
public static event ExitAction OnChunkExited;

private bool exited = false;

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    CarTag carTag = other.GetComponent<CarTag>();
    if (carTag != null)
    {
        if (!exited)
        {
           exited = true;
           OnChunkExited();
           StartCoroutine(WaitAndDestroy());
        }
    }
}
    
IEnumerator WaitAndDestroy()
{
   
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    // Destroy the LevelBlock
    var block = GameObject.FindWithTag("LevelBlock");
    Destroy(block);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindWithTag` returns the very first encountered GameObject with according tag.

The object you actually want to destroy is the parent of your `ExitTrigger` which has the `LevelBlockScript` attached.

You could pass it on like e.g.

```
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    CarTag carTag = other.GetComponent<CarTag>();
    if (carTag != null)
    {
        if (!exited)
        {
           exited = true;
           OnChunkExited();
           StartCoroutine(WaitAndDestroy(GetComponentInParent<LevelBlockScript>().gameObject));

           // or also simply
           //StartCoroutine(WaitAndDestroy(transform.parent.gameObject))
        }
    }
}
    
IEnumerator WaitAndDestroy(GameObject block)
{
   
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    // Destroy the LevelBlock
    Destroy(block);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your script this

```
 // Destroy the LevelBlock
var block = GameObject.FindWithTag("LevelBlock");
Destroy(block);
```

is just grabbing the first object with tag LevelBlock and deleting it.

I am gathering that the script you provided is on the block. If that is the case then fixing it is pretty straight forward. Maybe something like

```
IEnumerator WaitAndDestroy()
{
   
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    // Destroy the LevelBlock
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

again this is under the assumption that this script lives on your block, but the `Destroy(gameObject)` (with a lowercase g) tells it to destroy itself.

EDIT: My bad I haven't touched unity in a while you need to get the parent object and destroy that

```
var parent = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
```

there are many ways to do this and it depends how your objects are set up but this will get you the parent object and then you can destroy that.

Comment: The script is on an ExitTrigger object, so this code just deletes it but the block stays. :/